# A dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

let's say I have a real estate website and In the default page i want to let the users to get the number of posts that fits to his parameters

I added
 [a link to an example image](http://cantrolfreak.com/default.aspx?word=Myrealastate)

the counter should react to every change and show the user the number automatically (this will do in ajax jquery)

I wrote a query but it will work only if all parameters are filled in, and i want to enable to fill in a few and still get the counter to work

here is the query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE shahar30_nadlan.CountPropertyResultsByquery 


@AreaID         int,
@DealID        int,
@PropertyTypeId int,
@FieldMax      int,
@FieldMin      int,
@RoomsMax      decimal,
@RoomsMin      decimal,
@PriceMax      int,
@PriceMin      int,
@ParkingSpace  bit,
@Elevator      bit,
@Aircondition  bit,
@Furniture     bit,
@Warehouse     bit,
@Balkony       bit,
@handicapped  bit, 
@Immediate    bit,
@Description  NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS
BEGIN


select count(*) from Tbl_Property
where AreaID        = @AreaID         and 
  DealID        = @DealID         and
  PropertyTypeId= @PropertyTypeId and
  Field  <= @FieldMax        and
  Field  >= @FieldMin        and
  Rooms  <= @RoomsMax        and
  Rooms  >= @RoomsMin        and
  Price  <= @PriceMax        and
  Price  >= @PriceMin       and
  ParkingSpace = @ParkingSpace   and
  Elevator = @Elevator       and
  Aircondition = @Aircondition   and
  Furniture = @Furniture      and
  Warehouse = @Warehouse      and
  Balkony = @Balkony        and
  handicapped = @handicapped    and
  [Immediate] = @Immediate      and
  Description like  '%' + @Description + '%' 

END
```

thank you,
shahar nardia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**not**  all parameters should be filled in

if a value wasnt supply so its null (unless it has a default val) and then :

The pattern which you should use is  :

```
select * from myTable where 

(  @companyId  IS NULL  OR ( companyId = @companyId ))
and
 ( @Name IS NULL  OR ( Name  = @Name ))
and
...
```

---

or

```
 (   companyId  = isnull(@companyId,companyId ))
      and
  (    Name = isnull(@Name ,Name ))
      and

    ...
```

coalesce can be used here also - but its slower. ( than is null)

Comment: Why would `COALESCE()` be slower?

Comment: @ypercube because it has been tested http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/performance-coalesce-null/

Comment: That blog compares `COALESCE()` with `IS NULL`. Not with `ISNULL()`

Comment: I meant is null and not isnull. the coalesce comparesion is regarding to is null.

Comment: Then your wording is not clear. I suggest you edit so it is obvious what you mean (that using functions, `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` is slower than `@something IS NULL` comparison).

Answer (score 2):

did you try optional parameters? here is an example:

```
@PriceMin      int = 1,
```

you can set default values like that, then you pass only the parameters you want and leave the rest to take the default values.